# Верстка подписи для электронного письма HTML

Tags: html, css

Задача сверстать подпись для электронного письма.

В инете мало информации на эту тему (возможно не правильно ищу). А те статьи, которые нашла, очень древние.

Нет понимания как подключать стили, шрифты и изображения. В старых статьях пишут, что стили д.б. инлайновые (прописаны в самом html)...

Поделитесь, может у кого есть ссылка на хорошую статью, и буду благодарна за любые советы по теме.
Спасибо)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/, support  - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Меняйте, добавляйте, украшайте)

```html
<style type="text/css">

.Podpis {
padding: 40px;
border: 2px double black; 
} 

.Image {
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 2px;
}

</style>

   
<div class="Podpis">
  
<div>
     <img src="1.jpg" class="Image" width="90" height="90" align="Left"  
</div>

<div align="Right">
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Autor:</b></td><td>Mister X</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Adress:</b></td><td>Sity</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Tel:</b></td><td>+8XXXXXXXXX</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Mail:</b></td><td>XXXXX@mail.ru</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Вариант, где **style** записывается в блоках.

```html
<div style="padding: 40px; border: 2px double black; ">
  
<div>
     <img src="1.jpg" width="90" height="90" align="Left" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 2px;"> 
</div>

<div align="Right">
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Autor:</b></td><td>Mister X</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Adress:</b></td><td>Sity</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Tel:</b></td><td>+8XXXXXXXXX</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><b>Mail:</b></td><td>XXXXX@mail.ru</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: только, как мне подсказали лучше стили писать в самих блоках, а не в тегах `style`

Comment: Не за что! Вполне! Вот как вариант того же примера с записью в блоках.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще нашла [такую штуку](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html), может кому пригодится.